# Adding a control variable in logistic regression with SPSS

Tags: command, spss

I am working with SPSS and want to control my analysis for the variable "age". How can I add a control variable when conducting a logistic regression? Would that be through an interaction term?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you have a number of variables that you are testing as to whether you want to include them within your final model build but you want to ensure that Age is definitely one of these.

In which case you need to have the following syntax:

```
    LOGISTIC REGRESSION VARIABLES Target_Var
      /METHOD=ENTER Age
      /METHOD=FSTEP(WALD) Var1 Var2 Var3
      /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) ITERATE(20) CUT(.5).
```

Change FSTEP(WALD) to whatever you require in terms of logistic regression method.